# Playing flash video full screen

Tags: html, flash

We are posting a video in our website.Video created by Adobe Captivate(.swf file). I am doing this by using object tag. The problem is flash player doesn't have fullscreen option.So we have to set size of flash using width and height parameters. But Its not possible to give width and height suitable for all resolutions.So is there any way to give video height relative to PC resolution? Or is there any way to play flash in full screen? By the way we are using flash player 11.6 with active_x

**UPDATE**
I have tried your swiffit method..here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "11.6.0");
                    swffit.fit("myFlashContent", 1000, 590);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="myFlashContent">
                <param name="movie" value="D:\desktop\BS demo.swf">
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="D:\desktop\BS demo.swf" width="800" height="600">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But fullscreen not working.. Is there anything i am missing? do i have to change anything in swiffit.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I see one problem, that is you seem to have forgotten to include the allow full screen parameter. try adding

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

I have no previous experience with actionscript, so I won't be able to help you with your .swf file, but I'm sure you will find this [article about working with full screen mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html)
useful.